# How can I send bitcoin from one address to another through the Bitcoin client/API?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

How can I send bitcoin from one address to another via Bitcoin client/API ?

There exist an API call called:

`sendfrom   <fromaccount> <tobitcoinaddress> <amount> [minconf=1] [comment] [comment-to]`

can I use it? And replace `<fromaccount>` with the `<bitcoinaddress>` to send bitcoin?

**Editing:**

i means i want transfer bitcoins from one address in my wallet to another address in my wallet ?

i used it in website each user have bitcoin address and balance so i want transfer just money exist in this address to another ?

i search for accounts in bitcoind but i found issue on it :

> The accounts code does not scale up to thousands of accounts with tens
>   of thousands of transactions, because by-account (and
>   by-account-by-time) indices are not implemented. So many operations
>   (like computing an account balance) require accessing every wallet
>   transaction.

how can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you answered your own question in a way. That command will send from a specified account to an address, I'm sure you don't want to bother with accounts and just send bitcoins.

You can send from an address to another using a similar command.

`sendtoaddress <bitcoinaddress> <amount> [comment] [comment-to]`

Where `<bitcoinaddress>` is the address you want to send to and `<amount>` is amount of Bitcoins (up to 8 decimal places). The other two that are in brackets are optional and cosmetic.

You can issue these commands in a command line or using one of the many libraries for various languages. Check out the [Bitcoin API reference](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29).

Comment: command sendtoaddress transfer from my wallet to another address, i want to transfer from only one address to another address in my wallet ?

Answer (score 1):

```
move - <fromaccount> <toaccount> <amount>
```

The move function will allow you to move funds from one address to another within your wallet. In regards to the scaling of accounts issue this could be resolved by connecting your own back end tracking system such as a database that stores and indexes by account.

Comment: but it require also create accounts in my wallet that not exceed thousands ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is exactly you do it however `[minconf=1]` `[comment]` `[comment-to]` is not mandatory